# Auto-implemented get/set properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties, accessor, automatic-properties

Is there any downside to letting C# create the private backing fields that are generated by using the automatic property creation (ie {get; set})?

I am aware that it is automatic and therefore you cannot customize the get/set, and would like to know if there are any other implications.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really an issue. You can easily convert an automatic property to a manual property later, if you discover that you need some feature or other. It's not a breaking change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `BinaryFormatter`, changing to (or from) automatically implemented properties is a breaking change, since field names matter to BF. Of course, one easy fix there is: don't use BF!

You also can't add attributes to the backing *field* using automatic properties.

No field initialisers.

No true `readonly` for use with immutability.

You can't add logic, obviously; no laziness, validation, side-effects or notification events.

With structs, you need to call `:this()` on custom constructors, which is ugly.

Otherwise though: they are great. I'm a big fan.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest issue that I have come across is that it is often very limiting when looking at binding scenarios. Typically when using data binding you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) which is not supported by the automatic properties.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is that you can't work with the backing fields, since they are created by the compiler.  This means you can't declare them const or readonly, it means you can't add logic around accessing them (lazy initialization, for example), etc.  The good news is that starting with the autoproperty makes the refactor to using a backing field easy, when you have a reason.